# Dynamic SVG pattern as a background: is it possible? I'll put an example

Tags: html, svg

Is it possible to put a dynamic SVG pattern as a background in HTML? For example: [Dynamic SVG code example][1]...Putting it as a background and then put divs over it like if it were a normal background, that's my question

[1]: https://codepen.io/terabaud/pen/abvGdYq`<svg> </svg>`

Comment: I see, thanks, you've answered my question.How do I choose it as my answer? It doesn't give me the option

Comment: I've converted the comment to an answer, you can choose it now if you wish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to animate it using SMIL or CSS animation because scripts don't run in background images.